# PrimeNG FullCalendar height and week/month/day not working

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I am using PrimeNG 8.1.1 FullCalendar in an application which uses Angular 8 and I have the following code

```
 @ViewChild("fullCalendar", { static: false }) fullCalendar: any;
   
    this.options = {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
      defaultDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      aspectRatio: 1.15,
      height:"auto",
      header: {
        left: "prev,next,today",
        center: "title",
        right: "agendaWeek,agendaDay,month"
      },
      editable: false,
      dayMaxEvents: true,
      eventRender: (e) => {
        e.el.innerHTML = e.el.innerText;
      },
      dateClick: (e) => {
        this.dateClicked(e);
      }
    };
  }
```

and in the template file, I have

```
<p-fullCalendar
  [styleClass]="'fullcalendar'"
  #fullCalendar
  [events]="calendarData"
  [options]="options"
></p-fullCalendar>
```

Here, I am trying to limit the height of the calendar so that it will appear on the page without scrolling. But this is not working and to see the full calendar, I need to scroll. Also the right buttons for month/day/week is also not appearing. I am following the documentation, but not sure what went wrong here.

Can you please help ?

Comment: Or at least a screenshot of what you mean? Also is the calendar inside any other HTML elements whose height/width is controlled by CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I was using FullCalendar Version 4 and I updated my configuration as shown below. Now everything is working fine.

```
this.options = {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
      defaultDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      contentHeight: 'auto',
      height:'parent',
      allDayDefault: false,
      header: {
        left: "prev,next,today",
        center: "title",
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
      },
      editable: false,
      dayMaxEvents: true,
      eventRender: (e) => {
        e.el.innerHTML = e.el.innerText;
      },
      dateClick: (e) => {
        this.dateClicked(e);
      }
    };
```